# installing hdf5, mattorch/matio for lua/torch

Tags: lua, torch

I am configuring the packages for torch.I can't install these packages using `luarocks`.

for the matio, I followed the instruction on github, the matio is installed. But I cannot require it. 
for the hdf5,see following.

Does anyone know what is the problem? I am new to Lua. Thanks very much!

```
$luarocks install hdf5
then I got the error information:
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.5.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
  Could NOT find HDF5: Found unsuitable version "", but required is at least
  "1.8" (found HDF5_hdf5_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.5.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:386 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.5.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindHDF5.cmake:398 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:4 (FIND_PACKAGE)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/tmp/luarocks_hdf5-20-0-5408/torch-hdf5/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

Error: Build error: Failed building.
```

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem on ubuntu >= 13.04, this command solves my problem:

```
sudo apt-get install libhdf5-serial-dev hdf5-tools
```

Then you can use luarocks to install hdf5

```
luarocks install hdf5
```

For other systems, you can reference [this link](https://github.com/deepmind/torch-hdf5/blob/master/doc/usage.md) for dependencies.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks! I believe this should be the accepted answer.